# Mui / Material UI 5 : How to remove the open next view / open previous view buttons from StaticTimePicker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

how do I remove the `open next view` and `open previous view` arrow buttons from the MUI `StaticTimePicker`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `slotProps` property.

For example:

```
<StaticTimePicker
    slotProps={
      {
        nextIconButton: { sx: { display: 'none' } },
        previousIconButton: { sx: { display: 'none' } }
      }
    }
    defaultValue={dayjs("2022-04-17T15:30")}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with the API and this probably should not be considered an 'answer', but if everything else fails, why don't you try some CSS to hide the elements:

```
div.MuiClockPicker-root > div.MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-root {
  display:none;
}
```